# What happens when a MySQL table is optimized and someone else is running a transaction on it?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

I'm curious what the outcome is for the following situation:

- `user_a` is running a "TABLE OPTIMIZE" query on a table during a transaction.
- `user_b` is performing another transaction at the same time in whcih queries on that same table that contain id's that are going to no longer exist because the "OPTIMIZE" query will alter the table and resort to the lowest auto increment id.

So let's say `user_b` did an `INSERT` and got the last insert id to use for some other purpose (foreign key assignment afterwards, or to pass back to an ajax call), and then `user_a` runs the `OPTIMIZE` on the table, which removes that id in the optimization process.

`user_a` commits the transaction....  would `user_b` be left with an invalid/non-existent id?  How does this work out?

Sorry if it's documented and very obvious :)

Comment: If you are using InnoDb, check the docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html#optimize-table-innodb-details) that says that `OPTIMIZE TABLE` changes auto increment IDs.

Comment: No (major) MySQL version released in this decade will reset the `auto_increment` value. On the other hand, no MySQL version released in the last decade supports `optimize` to be performed online (which means that `insert` will wait until `optimize` is finished). Also, no mysql version allows `optimize` to be executed inside a transaction; any ddl statement (`alter`, `create`, ...) will implicitly commit any ongoing transaction. So I guess it will work out fine after all.